# Recessively query Redis based on data type

Tags: redis

I am representing JSON objects in Redis by flattening the JSON path keys like so:

### JSON object

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "address": {
                "street": "12 Rainbow Avenue",
                "country": "Fuzzyland"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "Billy Bob",
            "address": {
                "street": "8 Rocky Lane",
                "country": "Fraggleville"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Redis entries

```javascript
users // SET [0, 1]
users:0 // SET [name, address]
users:0:name // STRING "John Smith"
users:0:address // SET [street, country]
users:0:address:street // STRING "12 Rainbow Avenue"
users:0:address:country // STRING "Fuzzyland"
users:1 // SET [name, address]
users:1:name // STRING "Billy Bob"
users:1:address // SET [street, country]
users:1:address:street // STRING "8 Rocky Lane"
users:1:address:country // STRING "Fraggleville"
```

As you can see, for properties that are arrays or object literals I am using a Redis SET to store the available keys.

It is easy enough for me to convert the JSON object to this structure using Node. However I am not experienced enough with Redis to write recursive queries that stitch together a complex result.

For example, say I want to get all the keys and values for `users:1`. How do I write a query that looks at the value of `users:1` sees that it is a SET so uses the values from that as another set of query keys?

Comment: Did you consider just using ReJSON instead of flattening it? https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/

Comment: I am using Redis as an AWS service which currently doesn't provide support for Redis modules... but thank you it is a possible future solution. ;)

Comment: mmm... RedisLabs VPC managed solution does https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/vpc/... just saying...